# Textview in center below of imageview Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, textview

how are you going today.

I want to know something where i stuck today.I am getting json of image and text in a list and my image is circular.When i get image with text it looks so bad because text is not in center below imageview.I searched a lot on this but i didn't find.I just found gravity "center" and center in parent "true",i tried both of these but i did not got solution.My code is:-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity>


<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/img_design" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/img_design"
    android:id="@+id/design_color"
    android:text=" "
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want like this automatically text set in middle of image because length is not fixed of text:

```
         IMAGEVIEW
           text
```

Please guide me,suggest me and give solution of this problem and if you have any query in my question then please ask me.Thank you.

Comment: As it's on UI, please attach a picture showing the problem, and possibly one to show what you would like to accomplish instead

Comment: Sir its done Thank you to try solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your layout with below XML code.

Here no need to take extra layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_design"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    tools:src="@drawable/profile_sidemenu"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/design_color"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/img_design"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    tools:text="This is sample text"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Output:**

[image: Layout of above code]

Comment: @GouravManuja its work because root relative layout width is `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` check again

Comment: but sir i have no need to change in Textview 

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/img_design"
        android:id="@+id/design_color"
        android:text="Design Color"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

i write like this just it works,so don't make complex to your code.Thank you sir

Answer (score 1):

use this i hpe it will work like charm. make and separate parent for both imageview and textview like below and try .. use your own circular imageview you are using

enter code here//schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_design"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:src="@color/white"
      />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="TextView"
     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/img_design" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the code, _android:layout_centerInParent_ makes no sense to me, and you want instead to center the text horizontally. Also, if you want both the circular image and the text to be a group which is centered in their parent, you should add one more layout which wraps around both, and center that in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Your layout will work if you keep width as `wrap_content` to your relative and `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` for TextView instead of center in parent. If you want full screen then use below layout

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_design"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/design_color"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text=" "
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Sir i am trying own with relative layout and its done Thanx to try solve my problem.I want to +1 to your answer but i can't cause of 15 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping `<CircleImageView>` and `<TextView>` in a `<LinearLayout>` with vertical orientation, and center `<LinearLayout>`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_design"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img_design" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below XML code

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_design"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/design_color"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Gaurav Manuja.. Ist Okay. Upvote the answer iif its helps you too

Comment: sir i can't cause of 15 reputation please +1 to my question to increase my reputation.